# Can AWS Lambda Replace an entire Rest Api layer in an enterprise web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and havebeen reading about aws lambda. Its very useful but you still have to write individual lambda functions instead of as a whole. i am wondering practically if its possible AWS Lambda can replace an entire Rest Api layer in an enterprise web application

Comment: The short answer is yes, it can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, everything is possible in the computer world but you need to answer lambda-serverless is the best way for me?

For example, you need smaller business flow per lambda(lambda have some hardware limits and need short computing and starting time for cost savings), that's mean you must separate your flow, its success depends on your business area and implementation. is your working area fit for this? But Lambda can handle almost everything with other AWS services(to be honest, maybe in some cases, lambda is a bit harder than the current system and community support is less than traditional systems but it also has lots of advantages as you know). You can check [this repo, it full-serverless booking app](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-airline-booking) and [this serverless e-commerce repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-ecommerce-platform).

To sum up, if your team is ready for it, you can start the conversion from some part of your application and check everything is ok. This answer totally depends on your team and business BCS nothing is impossible and that's engineering. 
That's my opinion because your question looks like a comment question.